# Jsoup parsing just output null

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

i making an app to get raw files from my olympus camera.
i can connect to it via wifi and go to 192.168.0.10 or oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP to get list of pictures, but when i tap on some of it, i get preview only and so i need just replace oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP/FILE.html?/DCIM/100OLYMP/ to  oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP/ to download raw file. So app need just replace all links on this page and show it on screen.
sounds easy.

so i connect jsoup:

implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.16.1'
and download this version from official web site

next i made a htmlparser java class:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class HTMLParser {
    public String getHTML(String url) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP").get();
            return doc.html();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

and then in main activity i add

```
package com.oly.rawshare;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        HTMLParser parser = new HTMLParser();
        String htmlCode = parser.getHTML("oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP");

        if (htmlCode != null) {
            htmlCode = htmlCode.replace("<img src=\"100OLYMP_files/title.gif\" width=\"300px\" height=\"27px\" alt=\"TITLE\">\n<hr color=\"#2E2E2E\">\n<div style=\"position: relative;\">\n<div style=\"background-color: #2E2E2E; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid #2E2E2E;\">\n<div align=\"left\">\n<font color=\"#929292\">&gt;</font><a href=\"oishare/DCIM\"><font color=\"#929292\">DCIM</font></a><font color=\"#929292\">&gt;</font>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar path = location.pathname;\nvar dcf = path.split(\"/\");\ndocument.write('<font color=\"#929292\">'+dcf[2]+'</font>');\n</script><font color=\"#929292\">100OLYMP</font>\n\n<br>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n", "");
            htmlCode = htmlCode.replace("oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP/FILE.html?/DCIM/100OLYMP/", "oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP/");
        }
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlCode, "text/html", "en_US", null);
    }
}
```

but for unknown reason i just get null in output string :(

yeah... idk what's the problem and i can't fix it..

Comment: Well, there is a `return null` in your exception handler, so that would be my first guess.

Comment: yeah, but that means that `
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP").get();
            return doc.html(); `
doesn't work

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. There's even a `e.printStackTrace();` which will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Your method `public String getHTML(String url)` has `url` parameter *which you are not using*. Instead of `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP").get();` you probably want `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();`

Comment: Pshemo, yeah, it was like this, but doesn't work, so i decided to change it to my url

Answer (score 1):

The *[connect](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect(java.lang.String))* method will parse the value to a *[URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html)* object, thus a *MalformedURLException* will be thrown.

For example.

```java
URL url = new URL("oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP");
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:764)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:646)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:582)
    at Example.main(Example.java:12)
```

Use the *[parse](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse(java.io.File))* method for files.

```java
d = Jsoup.parse(new File("oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP"));
```

Comment: yeah, no protocol, because if I left it, then my question would be perceived by the forum as spam
there is http oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP, of course

Comment: oh, i can't understand what i do wrong, i just can't make it work.. where i need to put this code lines?