# Simple jsoup parsing and webview output

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

i am new to android studio and now i tried to make a simple app, that just get html code from page https://www.oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP/, replace http://oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP/FILE.html?/DCIM/100OLYMP/ with http://oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP/ and show this edited page in web view inside the app..
i used jsoup and my app just crashed when i try to get a html code.... so now i use "catch return null;" and it doesn't crash now, but (obviously) it doesn't work still...
i just don't understand what i do wrong...

```
public class HTMLParser {
    public String getHTML(String url) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            return doc.html();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

please keep in mind that I'm not very good at android studio...

p.s.
it's an app for my olympus camera, that i want to use to get raw pics from it.. for this i just need to connect to wifi, that it share, go to oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP inside my browser, tap on any photo i like and then replace oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP/FILE.html?/DCIM/100OLYMP with oishare/DCIM/100OLYMP, then i press enter and file will download through my browser.. i just need to automate this process so i don't need to make this for every photo i need..

Comment: How this question differs from the one you've posted here yesterday?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jsoup parsing just output null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77166854/jsoup-parsing-just-output-null)